# Como executar uma função jquery/javascript apenas no load da página e evitar postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, ajaxtoolkit

Olá.

Tenho uma função para "criar" um [Accordion do jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) na minha *div*.

Acontece que dentro desta minha *div* existem vários controles que fazem *post* na página. O que eu quero é que, ao fazer um *post* na página, o meu *accordion* mantenha o estado, ou seja, se ele estiver aberto, quero que ele se mantenha aberto, caso esteja fechado, quero que ele permaneça fechado.

**Segue o código que "cria" o *Accordion***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    accordion();
});

function accordion() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            // faço algumas coisas aqui.
        }
    });
}
```

O problema de "criar" o *accordion* no `$(document).ready` é que ele será recriado a cada *post* da página.

**Adendo**: Estou usando também o [UpdatePanel do AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx) para manter os estados dos meus controles da página.

Como faço para a minha função **`accordion();`** ser chamada apenas uma vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal em vez de você jogar essa responsabilidade para o lado do backend é manter isso no front end. Então salve o estado dele no cookie.

E então faça a verificação no javascript lendo do cookie o seu state.

no beforeActive você salva um cookie, por exemplo. Accordion: true.

```
function accordion() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            document.cookie="accordion=true";
            //coloque uma lógica aki para setar para false quando ele já existir e for true, use algum plugin de cookie de jquery para facilitar sua vida
        }
    });
}
```

quando for instanciar o accordion faça uma verificação

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(document.cookie.indexOf("accordion=true;") == -1){
          accordion();
        }
    });
```

Comment: a linha `document.cookie.indexOf("accordion=true;")` retorna sempre -1, sendo assim ele sempre executara a função `accordion()`. E isto é exatamente o que eu não quero. Preciso que esta função `accordion()` seja executada apenas uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
var isPostBack = <%=Page.IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower()%>; // 

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!isPostBack) { 
        accordion();
    }
});
```

Case precisar da versão com razor mude a declaração assim:

```
var isPostBack = @Page.IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower(); // versão com razor
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas neste caso o `isPostBack` é sempre _true_ então ele sempre irá "recriar" meu **accordion** que é exatamente o que eu não quero. Se eu deixar para chamar a função `accordion()` somente quando o `isPostBack` for _false_ o meu **accordion** nunca será criado.

Comment: Vou tentar outra abordagem, vc está usando Razor?

Comment: Outro detalhe que passou despercebido, é que vc só quer chamar o accordion caso não seja postback.

Comment: Não estou utilizando Razor. Estou usando ASP.NET com UpdatePanel do AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar veja se isso funciona.

Comment: Acontece a mesma coisa, o `isPostBack` é sempre _true_ e sendo assim ele nunca "cria" o _accordion_.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema trabalhando com *Coockie* como o @RenanBorges sugeriu e os eventos do próprio [**Accordion**](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/). Para gerenciar os *cookies* eu utilizei o ***[jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)***.

**O resultado final ficou assim:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var abertoOuFechado = 0;
      if ($.cookie('active') != null) {
        if (isNumber($.cookie('active'))) {
          abertoOuFechado = $.cookie('active', Number);
        } else {
          abertoOuFechado = $.cookie('active', Boolean);
        }
        $.removeCookie('active');
      }

      accordion(abertoOuFechado);
    }

    function accordion(abertoOuFechado) {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0,
        create: function(event, ui) {
          $.removeCookie('active');
          $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", abertoOuFechado);
        },
        activate: function(event, ui) {
          var active = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active");
          $.cookie('active', active, {
            expires: 1
          });
        }
      });
    }
```